# Where do Docker containers and Kubernetes pods write to disk in absence of a volume?

Tags: hard-drive, file-management, docker, io, kubernetes

General question about the internals of Docker and containers running in Kubernetes when using the Docker engine.

Docker containers are ephemeral, meaning that if a container is destroyed, any data that was written to the internals of that container is gone.  This leads me to my question:

If one starts a container containing an application which writes a file to a directory that is not backed by a volume, to where does said file actually get written?  Is it actually written to disk?  Is it actually written to main memory and then just flushed to disk once `docker stop` occurs?  Is it something else?

Same question(s) for a Docker container that is a pod running in Kubernetes.  Are the mechanics the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker data is only kept in host memory for "tmpfs mounts".
You may read about how to create such mounts in the article
[Use tmpfs mounts](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/volumes/tmpfs/).

All other non-persistent data is is kept in the *writable layer* of the container,
which is an entire file-system managed by the
[storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/).
This data doesn’t persist after the container is deleted (but does persist if it
is only suspended or stopped), and both read and write speeds are lower than
native file system performance, since they pass through the storage driver
before passing to the host disk driver.

More than one storage driver are available for Docker, as described in the article
[Docker storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/).

It is not specified in the documentation where the writable layer of a container
is stored on the disk, probably in order to let each implementation of a
storage driver the freedom of making the best choice.

To see what storage driver your Docker engine is using, run:

```
$ sudo docker info
```

If you’re using the Docker default storage driver, you may see something like this:

[image]

Using the above information, my guess would be that the writable layers
of all containers would be
stored under the folder `/var/lib/docker/aufs`, where `aufs` stands for the
storage driver used (but this is only a guess).